# Typecasting datetime differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, firebird

We use firebird as a local testing database and most of our clients use SQL Server or Oracle.

This works in MS SQL Server, but not in Firebird. (haven't tested it n Oracle yet)

```
CONVERT(char(8),MAX(p.end_Time)-MIN (p.start_Time),8) as duration
```

is there a way to acoomplish this same thing for (Firebird, Oracle, and MS Sql Server)?

thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need it to be in `hh:mi:ss`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Firebird you need to use [`DATEDIFF`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-datediff.html) to obtain a difference between two timestamps (datetimes). This BTW is similar to the [SQL Server `DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx). If you then want to cast it to char, you can use [`CAST`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-cast.html), eg `CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, MAX(p.end_Time), MIN(p.start_Time)) AS CHAR(8))` should do the trick (or you can simply do `CAST(MAX(p.end_Time) - MIN (p.start_Time) AS CHAR(8))` as timestamps are subtractable.

I just noticed though that the option you specify in your `CONVERT` will convert to `hh:mi:ss`. There is no such option in Firebird. If you need to convert specifically to `hh:mi:ss`, you might want to look at UDF libraries like [FreeAdhocUDF](http://freeadhocudf.org/documentation_english/dok_eng_datum.html#umwandeln) (specifically `F_SECONDS2PERIOD`) or [rFunc UDF](http://rfunc.sourceforge.net/rfunc.htm). If all else fails, you could write your own UDF.

Comment: What is your Firebird version, and what is the query you use; also make sure you didn't add too many braces.

Comment: I copied your exact code from above! When I use your alternative, I get a conversion error from string

Comment: Also, I ntoice you dont use the AS Duration in your statement

Comment: The problem is that the result of the substraction is a `double precision`, so most likely the result is longer than 8 characters, so you get an error due to the overflow on conversion. You may need to convert to a `DECIMAL` first. Regarding the `AS Duration`, I didn't include that as it is irrelevant to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice when it comes to SQL, this is why I have come here to ask for the help of you EXPERTS. To Say "I didn't include that as it is irrelevant to my answer" does not help me. I would also need the help with the decimal conversion. Although I appreciate your answer and help, it hasn;t gotten me one step further - since the SQL does not work on either of my databases.

Comment: To clarify: `AS Duration` only specifies an alias for your resultset, it has no relevance in **my answer**; if you need it in your query, then you can include it in your query. You might want to clarify your question further to include the output you want, and why you need that output (maybe there is a better way).

Answer (score 0):

there is no CONVERT on firebird.

Use CAST:

`select cast(MAX(p.end_Time) as varchar(50))` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle (Oracle 8i, Oracle 9i, Oracle 10g, Oracle 11g), you can use to_char function:

```
   select to_char( value, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] ) ....
```

Example:

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR ( SYSDATE - TO_DATE ( '18-10-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy' ), '9,999.99' ) as duration FROM   DUAL;
```

Here is the link for [Oracle/PLSQL: To_Char Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: As I statend in my comments above, i need a solution for all my databases (Firebird, SQL Server, and ORACLE)